# How can I set the options for a MySQL Connector/Python X DevAPI connection?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-x-devapi

How can I set the ["--local-infile[={0|1}]"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile) option for a mysqlx connection?

My python code looks the following:

```
import mysqlx

# Connect to server on localhost
session = mysqlx.get_session({
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 33060,
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '12345678',
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no `LOAD DATA` support in the X Protocol, which means that X DevAPI clients don't provide such an option. You'll need a Classic Protocol connection for that.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js